# JMeter with sikulixapi

Tags: jmeter, sikuli-x

I want to use sikulixapi with JMeter.

This is my code in the JMeter Beanshell sampler.

```
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.KeyModifier;
import org.sikuli.script.Match;
import java.io.IOException;
Screen screen = new Screen();
Pattern VNCviewer = new Pattern ("C:\\patterns\\openvncviewer\\eclipse.png");
screen.click(VNCviewer);
```

Im getting the below error while executing the JMeter script.

```
Response code:500
Response message:org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException:
Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: 
`` import org.sikuli.script.Pattern; import 
org.sikuli.script.Screen; import org.s . . . '' 
Typed variable declaration : Object constructor
```

Im using sikulixapi-2.0.5.jar and this jar has copied to the lib/ext folder.

Please let me know what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need to put the jar to "lib" folder, "lib/ext" is for [JMeter Components and Plugins](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. `sikulixapi-2.0.5.jar` alone is not enough, you need to add its [dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sikulix/sikulixapi/2.0.5). Full list would be something like:

   ```
   animal-sniffer-annotations-1.17.jar
   ant-1.9.7.jar
   ant-launcher-1.9.7.jar
   antlr-3.5.2.jar
   antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar
   asm-7.1.jar
   asm-analysis-7.1.jar
   asm-commons-7.1.jar
   asm-tree-7.1.jar
   asm-util-7.1.jar
   bcpkix-jdk15on-1.62.jar
   bcprov-jdk15on-1.62.jar
   checker-compat-qual-2.5.5.jar
   commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar
   commons-cli-1.4.jar
   commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
   commons-compress-1.19.jar
   commons-exec-1.3.jar
   commons-io-2.8.0.jar
   commons-logging-1.2.jar
   error_prone_annotations-2.3.2.jar
   failureaccess-1.0.1.jar
   fontbox-2.0.21.jar
   ghost4j-1.0.1.jar
   guava-28.0-android.jar
   icu4j-59.1.jar
   itext-2.1.7.jar
   j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
   jai-imageio-core-1.4.0.jar
   java-sizeof-0.0.5.jar
   javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar
   javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
   jbig2-imageio-3.0.3.jar
   jboss-logging-3.1.4.GA.jar
   jboss-vfs-3.2.15.Final.jar
   jffi-1.2.19-native.jar
   jffi-1.2.20.jar
   jline-2.14.5.jar
   jna-5.6.0.jar
   jna-platform-5.6.0.jar
   jnr-a64asm-1.0.0.jar
   jnr-constants-0.9.12.jar
   jnr-ffi-2.1.10.jar
   jnr-netdb-1.1.6.jar
   jnr-posix-3.0.50.jar
   jnr-x86asm-1.0.2.jar
   jsr305-3.0.2.jar
   jython-slim-2.7.2.jar
   lept4j-1.13.2.jar
   listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar
   log4j-1.2.17.jar
   netty-buffer-4.1.45.Final.jar
   netty-codec-4.1.45.Final.jar
   netty-common-4.1.45.Final.jar
   netty-handler-4.1.45.Final.jar
   netty-resolver-4.1.45.Final.jar
   netty-transport-4.1.45.Final.jar
   opencv-4.3.0-3.jar
   pdfbox-2.0.21.jar
   pdfbox-debugger-2.0.21.jar
   pdfbox-tools-2.0.21.jar
   py4j-0.10.9.1.jar
   reflections8-0.11.6.jar
   sikulix2tigervnc-1.1.4.jar
   sikulixapi-2.0.5.jar
   slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
   slf4j-nop-1.7.28.jar
   ST4-4.0.8.jar
   tess4j-4.5.4.jar
   xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar
   ```
3. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because Groovy performance is much better, moreover Groovy has better Java compatibility and offers a lot of [enhancements](https://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html) on top of normal Java SDK. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Maven coordinates for SikuliX 2.0.5 API should take care for the dependencies.

RaiMan from SikuliX